# Jenkinsfile not found

Tags: git, jenkins

I'm just starting out with Jenkins, and can't seem to get it to work. I created a text file called 'Jenkinsfile' in the root directory of my repository, but when I try to buil I'm getting the error "‘Jenkinsfile’ not found Does not meet criteria". This is the full Jenkins output:

```
Started by user Joshua Fishman [Thu Jul 20 11:44:10 EDT 2017]
Starting  branch indexing...
git.exe rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10 Setting origin to C:\Users\JoshuaF\git\<some_repo>
git.exe config remote.origin.url C:\Users\JoshuaF\git\<some_repo># timeout=10 Fetching origin...
Fetching upstream changes from origin
git.exe --version #timeout=10
git.exe fetch --tags --progress origin
+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
git.exe ls-remote --symref C:\Users\JoshuaF\git\<some_repo> # timeout=10    
git.exe rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10 Setting origin to C:\Users\JoshuaF\git\<some_repo>    
git.exe config remote.origin.url C:\Users\JoshuaF\git\<some_repo># timeout=10 
Fetching & pruning origin...  
Fetching upstream changes from origin   
git.exe --version # timeout=10    
git.exe fetch --tags --progress origin +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/* --prune  
Getting remote branches... 
Seen branch in repository origin/master  
Seen 1 remote branch

Checking branch master
      'Jenkinsfile' not found
    Does not meet criteria 
Processed 1 branches [Thu Jul 20 11:44:11 EDT 2017]
Finished branch indexing. Indexing took 0.68 sec
Finished: SUCCESS
```

and this is my repository:[image: repository]

Totally new to this, so I appreciate any help.

Comment: Is the `Jenkinsfile` versionned? It's in your folder, but not necessary in git.

Comment: I committed it, so it should be right? Is there a way to check? Pretty new to git too

Comment: Also, does it have a hidden `.txt` extension?

Comment: I tried to save it as 'all files', but that's definitely possible

Comment: In git bash launch `git show master:`. It will display the content of the root folder on branch 'master' which is what Jenkins checks.

Comment: Yes, it does. What file format should it be saved as?

Comment: It is 'Jenkinsfile.txt'. Is that the issue?

Comment: The '.txt' extension may be the issue: Jenkins is looking for 'Jenkinsfile' without extension. `git mv Jenkinsfile.txt Jenkinsfile && git commit` will rename the file.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The '.txt' extension may be the issue: Jenkins is looking for 'Jenkinsfile' without extension. `git mv Jenkinsfile.txt Jenkinsfile && git commit` will rename the file.

Comment: You should enable the display of file extension in file explorer: https://www.file-extensions.org/article/show-and-hide-file-extensions-in-windows-10